# Schengen visa: why bank statements if the company is sponsoring my visa?

Tags: schengen, work, belgium

I have a work permit for Belgium. I understand that my visa application will be sponsored by the Belgian company recruiting me. In this case, why am I stil required to submit my bank statements?

I am travelling on company sponsor and I am planning to sponsor my wife's travel. But the amount in my bank is sufficient for sustenance, but only for one individual(as per the Belgian per day euro calculation). Effectively both of us are financially covered, as I will get paid while staying in Belgium and my bank funds become useful for my wife's stay. But since both of us are submitting my bank statement with our visa applications, we are not sure how well it goes down with the authorities

Comment: What is the company sponsoring? Just travel? Also accommodation? Also all the food? For how many days? Do you do some vacation before of after visiting the company? Are you asking the visa just for 1 day?  As you see from such questions, most of cases, there is an needs for extra funds. [doesn't forget that such statements could also be used to validate the company]

Comment: Hi Giacomo, my company is effectively sponsoring everything for me: visa, ticketing, accommodation, per day allowance, even the local commute in the city I am travelling to. I am asking for visa for close to 50 days. During a brief period within my stay limits, I want my wife to accompany me(for 3 weeks). I will sponsor all her expenses. But the amount in my bank is sufficient for sustenance, but only for one individual(as per the Belgian per day euro calculation). Since we will be sharing my bank statements for both of our visa applications, I wanted to be clear on the finances.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are explicitly having your company as your sponsor, you can relax and go ahead with providing your bank statement for your application as well as for anybody whom you are planning to sponsor. Your bank statement's "money value" will be considered only for the visa application(s), for whom YOU are the sponsor.
It has worked for me.

Comment: This is the wrong answer, and accepting it is misleading to other readers of this question. Please change your acceptance to another answer.

Comment: Whats wrong with this @DJClayworth?

Comment: If you look at the other answers you will see that your bank statements ARE considered for your own applications, even if someone else is paying the costs of the trip.

Comment: I beg to differ, but that argument doesn't go along with all answers here. For reference, please find @George Y's answer below which also says that one's own bank statement is not applicable in this case. Also, I clearly mentioned that the amount of money in the bank is not checked against the amount neccesary to sustain in schengen region if you have your company as sponsor. Moreover, I have had a recent first hand experience on the aspect that if I have some sponsor, providing my own bank statements is only for the purpose of justifying good conduct and the trip is not going to  be a burden

Answer (score 11):

There is no explanation in the official Visa Code I could find. But bank statements have other usefulness besides the usual "ensure the applicant has enough resources to support yourself during the trip" which is not applicable in your case. For example the consulate could use them to ensure:

- That you have legitimate means to support yourself right now, i.e. receive legal income from work and spend it (i.e. your income is not all cash-based which could be linked to tax evasion and even possible criminal activities) - this helps ensuring that you'd do the same while in Belgium;
- That you have meaningful connection to your local economy - and thus is likely to return back once your work permit is finished/canceled, instead of staying underground in Belgium;
- That there are no obvious red flags which would require further questioning, such as your balance shows you have been in debt for a long period of time.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The whole point is that I am travelling on company sponsor and I am planning to sponsor my wife's travel. But the amount in my bank is sufficient for sustenance, but only for one individual(as per the Belgian per day euro calculation). Effectively both of us are financially covered, as I will get paid while staying in Belgium and my bank funds become useful for my wife's stay. But since both of us are submitting my bank statement with our visa applications, we are not sure how well it goes down with the authorities

Comment: @Blogger4Code Does your wife have any money on herself? I believe you could mention it somewhere and/or provide _her_ statement too.

Comment: Yes @yo', I plan to attach her deposit account summary along with her visa application. Also thinking about enclosing a copy of my credit card, if that works anyhow :)

Answer (score 5):

The bank statement shows that:

1. Your economic situation correlates with what you have submitted as your details.
2. That the trip is not a financial burden on you.
3. The company may not be covering the costs of the entire trip for you, or may only be covering them partially. For example, when I travel on company business the flights are covered by the company, but hotel expenses are not (they are reimbursed later). So I have to show sufficient funds for the trip even though a large majority of it is being paid for.

   My brother was recently hired by a company in the Netherlands. This company paid for his ticket, plus 3 months of hotel stay, plus a daily stipend (while they finished his paperwork and got him a permanent apartment); and my brother still had to show a bank statement as part of the visa procedure.

In summary, the bank statement is more than just how much money you have in the bank.

Comment: +1 for the some-costs-may-be-reimbursed-later note.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the company is sponsoring you and not your spouse. I don't think you can sponsor your wife, if you haven't started working with this company yet - Unless you have sufficient funds in your bank account for both of you and the bank statement and other documents demonstrate that your spouse has ties to her home country. This is how I think the Belgian authorities would look at your case.

Comment: Hi @Deans, I have been working with the company in India for almost 1 year now. I have been given the work permit for same company's Belgian counterpart. I am planning to present 3-4 months salary certificates (gained from the same company) in the visa application as well. As well as the salary certificate for the salary which I will earn in Belgium. Plus, I have a mention of the same company as my sponsor in my visa application. Do you think I am still not clear on the finances?

Comment: Hi Blogger4Code. The Belgian embassy has to decide if the income you show can sustain both of you in Belgium for the period of your stay. The only means for them to do that is your bank statement and salary slips. You might also want to demonstrate that you have enough assets in India to want to come back.

Comment: I agree to what you say Deans, but the point is: my income should not ideally be a determinant for my own sustenance, as I mentioned in my original query: I am mentioning my sponsor as my company in my visa application.

Answer (score -1):

The visa application process is just not optimized for saving you time and effort. For some applications the bank statement is important (such as when self-funding the trip), so they always ask for it.