# Applying for a Schengen visa using spouse's bank statement

Tags: schengen, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am going to apply for a Schengen tourist visa.
Is that possible for a husband to use his wife's bank account as we travel together?

Comment: Do you not have an account of your own? It is typically best for all applicants to provide their own bank statements, unless there’s a good reason why you don’t have an account. Statements help show your ties to your country of residence eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109294/schengen-visa-why-bank-statements-if-the-company-is-sponsoring-my-visa

Comment: i do have my own account but it is not really active as my wife and me work together as self-employed and we are using her account.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes, this is absolutely normal.**

A spouse often does not have an account of their own, or has one that only deals with small amounts of money. Or they may have only a single bank accoubt between them. (It was of course much more common back in the old days when husbands regularly managed money for their wives - but I digress.)

All you need to do is say that your wife is paying for the expenses of your trip. Then you should include both your bank accounts and hers with your application.

Answer (score 4):

They want to see two things about you:

- Your bank statements and what they say about your life circumstances.
- The source of the money for your travel, and that it is legitimate.

It is perfectly normal that one spouse pays for the travel of both partners. The spouse who pays for the travel should be able to afford it when one looks at the total circumstances.

But they still want to look at your account if you have one, e.g. for an *absence* of suspicious deposits, and for the presence of deposits and withdrawals which are normal for someone in your position. Normal is good when it comes to visas.

This [answer by Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) is about the UK, but the same principle applies elsewhere.

Comment: do i need to deposit some money to my bank account now? i have appointment in 2 weeks.

Comment: No, don't do that. Unexplained deposits are very suspicious. It isn't about the balance, it is about a nice, regular, long-term pattern.